# How do I access user meta data from my Wordpress website using SQL? Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to create an e-learning platform in Wordpress using LearnDash as our LMS (learning Management System).

LearnDash is a plugin that gives me the ability to create the entire course, quizzes, exams and more. LearnDash data is stored in my wordpress database. Therefor the user quiz data is in my Wordpress database. **Important user quiz data is stored in wp_usermeta table.**

I am using mySQL to query tables to generate quiz data. Eventually I will use these queried tables to make charts and graphs of the quiz data (for the students).

Problem:

I am having trouble querying the quiz data from the meta tables. I want to retrieve the student name, student ID, quiz name, quiz category, quiz score, time spent on quiz, and class average quiz score. **But more specifically I do not know how to access quiz data in the meta tables using SQL**.

Is it something to do activation keys, meta keys, and meta values? A lot of articles i have read use php to retrieve data from the meta tables but I need to know if it is possible to get the data via SQL.

Here is the Wordpress database schema (ERD):

[enter image description here][image: 1]

(if image doesnt appear the article below is where i pulled it from. Also if you need the LearnDash tables I can provide those as well but I dont think youll need them.)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Here is what I am trying in SQL:

```
SELECT wp_users.`ID`,
       wp_users.`display_name` AS Name,
       wp_posts.`post_title` AS Quiz Title,
       wp_posts.`post_type` AS Quiz,
FROM wp_users, 
     wp_learndash_pro_quiz_statistic, 
     wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'sfwd-quiz'
AND display_name = 'Nathan'
```

(data from wordpress tables and learndash tables)

this queries a table with some of the information i need but not all of it and not the important attributes (quiz score, ave class quiz score, quiz category and time spent on quiz). However, I also did not try and pull any data from the **wp_usermeta table**. Which is where those attributes are and which is what I don't understand how to do. Can anyone help me get the information i need?

Comment: Note, screenshots aren't as helpful as the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` schema dump of the relevant tables *trimmed for clarity*.

Comment: start by using joins instead of comma serperated tables, ,aybe this helps you